# My jar file will not execute

Tags: java, windows, jar

File `PrintTest.java`:

```
    public class PrintTest{
      public static void main(String[] args){
           System.out.println("Why are you executing me?");
      }
    }
```

File `Manifest.txt`

```
Main-Class: PrintTest
```

My command I ran to compress to `.jar`:

```
jar cfm PrintTest.jar Manifest.txt PrintTest.class
```

I also tried this (even though it doesn't matter):

```
jar cmf PrintTest.jar Manifest.txt PrintTest.class
```

My Directory Structure:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\PrintTest_jar`

`PrintTest_jar`: `PrintTest.java`, `PrintTest.class`, `Manifest.txt`, `PrintTest.jar`

When I double-click on the `.jar` file, nothing happens. No errors, nothing.

`PrintTest.class` runs fine from the command line. I'm also running on Windows.

Comment: What happens if you try to run it from the command line? `java -jar PrintTest.jar`

Comment: i get nothing from command line- however, PrintTest.class runs fine from it.

Comment: Are you sure, not even an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I double-click on the .jar file, nothing happens. No errors, nothing!

When launched like that, the console window will immediately disappear when the program has finished executing. To see the output, you should run the program from the console instead of double clicking the jar file.

**edit**: To delay the program termination, you could do this:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Press Enter to exit...");
 scanner.next();
```

However, I think it makes more sense to just run console applications from the console.

Comment: is there a way to delay the end of the program so it doesnt end as soon as its done printing?

Comment: it now says theres an error with all 3 lines :P thats okay though. i just wanted to know why i couldnt see the application. vote up for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code that was given to you to delay it is **correct**. However, you need to **import** an utility from Java libraries for it to work. Type in this before even your class body.

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

Comment: It has to be assumed that he has this import or the class would not run from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and the display of your manifest text file then you must ensure that the text file contains a new-line after the last line of text or it will not be processed properly. Please see this for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html

Answer (score 1):

My dear friend, your application is a DOS program and would only run in DOS, your did not create a GUI program, if it was a GUI program, it would at least display on the Computer.....DOS is meant for DOS..... sorry.